# Happy birthday — taking stock of our first year

Tags: discussion

Today it’s the first anniversary of Portuguese Language SE. So it’s a good time to take stock of how far we’ve come. Here are a few stats I got from around the site.

We now have 836 questions and 1,390 answers, which makes about 2.3 questions per day. But the graph below shows that the number of questions has generally decreased. There were lots of questions in the first few months, and rather fewer later, especially since late January. Let’s hope it doesn’t fall any further. All these graphs come from Site Analytics.

[image]

Votes have basically followed questions and answers, and you can see we hardly downvote. That’s because we have such great posts!

[image]

The number of visitors has been increasing over time, both new visitors and repeat visitors, which is good.

[image]

Our main problem, I think, is that we’re still such a small bunch. [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language) tells me we have now 1140 members. But really active members are much, much fewer.

If you click on [“users” on the menu bar](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) you can see each user’s rep. Right now there are 450 members with 1 rep, and 402 members with 101 rep. Nearly all of the latter are people who had enough reputation in other sites and got 101 rep the moment they joined Portuguese Language and never posted a thing (some may have got 101 by coincidence from posting, but I checked about a dozen at random, and none had any posts). This means we have only about 300 members that have ever posted a question or an answer. At the other end of the spectrum, just three members, who include me, posted over a third of all answers, and a slightly different group of three members posted 23% of all questions. So it would be good to have more people answering. And asking.

Voting is another way to engage with the community. There are at the moment 636 members with reputation 15 or higher and who can therefore upvote. If you click on [“users” and then “voters”](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) you can see everyone who has cast 11 votes or more since the moment they joined. To date only 110 members have done so. So there’s room for improvement here too.

So we’re a small bunch, but a small bunch of great people, and I’ve enjoyed this community immensely. I’m pretty sure you have too. Let’s hope more people join, and more people become active, and make this community bigger. Let’s keep it going.

Comment: Clap, clap, clap. Nice post Jacinto. Well done!

Comment: @JorgeB. Thanks. I wonder how we resisted the temptation to mark mensiversaries. It's so trendy theses days.

Comment: «[Happy birthday to the ground!](http://giphy.com/gifs/day-today-earth-wDRU6U1BVhwwo)»  (see the [full video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAYL5H46QnQ))

Comment: More worrying than the number of questions is the type of questions that are posted nowadays. The first questions on the frontpage are almost all about the origin of some word or expression, which 90% of the time one could file under trivia, as they give no special insight into the language. It also tells you that the site hasn't attracted learners.

Comment: Excellent analysis of our first year as a team.

Answer (score 4):

It's curious to see that
there are `about 300 members that have ever posted a question or an answer`,
but that `to date only 110 members have [voted]`...

This means that 2/3 of the members that posted questions or answers did not vote more than 10 times!
They seem to interact mostly with their own question/answer.

Comment: There might be some that have posted a question or answer and have less than 15 rep. Not many though, it would have to be a very lousy post (though there are execptions). But go and check for youself.